# Pandas ValueError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 7 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the value of BitCoin from an API. When I run the cell below i get the error mentioned in title. I am trying to follow a DataScience tutorial from FreeCodeCamp

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
def get_historic_price(symbol, exchange='bitfinex', after='2020-02-01'):
  url = 'https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/btcusd/ohlc'.format(symbol=symbol, exchange=exchange)
  resp = requests.get(url, params={'periods':'3600', 'after': str(int(pd.Timestamp(after).timestamp()))})
  resp.raise_for_status()
  data = resp.json()
  df = pd.DataFrame(data['result']['3600'], columns=['CloseTime', 'OpenPrice', 'LowPrice', 'ClosePrice', 'Volume', 'NA'])
  df['CloseTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CloseTime'], unit='s')
  df.set_index('CloseTime', inplace=True)
  return df

last_week = (pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.offsets.Day(7))
last_week
#Code works till here
btc = get_historic_price('btc', 'bitstamp', after = last_week)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `df.set_index('CloseTime', inplace=True)` line?

Comment: `columns=['CloseTime', 'OpenPrice', 'LowPrice', 'HightPrice', 'ClosePrice','NA', 'Volume']`Isn't this the name of the row?

Comment: @Marioanzas I am pretty sure the problem lies in the line "columns=['CloseTime', 'OpenPrice', 'LowPrice', 'HightPrice', 'ClosePrice','NA', 'Volume']" Edit: I also tried your suggestion but no success

Comment: @AKD in your last comment you are telling me that you are passing `columns=['CloseTime', 'OpenPrice', 'LowPrice', 'HightPrice', 'ClosePrice','NA', 'Volume']`. However, in the question you are passing `columns=['CloseTime', 'OpenPrice', 'LowPrice', 'ClosePrice', 'Volume', 'NA'])`, which is not the same given that `HightPrice` is missing. Maybe there is a mistake as that's the reason why it's giving you the error between 6 and 7 arguments?

Comment: @Marioanzas Thank You, I was trying to figure out what that data was, if following a proper order the result i am getting corresponds with highPrice as you mentioned. You were of great help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it turns out that the API has added more data. This data is not relevant to me so what is did was I added another column after 'NA', called 'NotNeeded'. It works perfectly now.